# how to create a system user account in db2 database

Tags: db2

I need to create a db2 user account. Any idea how to create a system user account in db2 database installed in Windows OS.

Based on the knowledge from googling, I believe - it needs to create a OS user. Do we have the steps to make this windows OS user to a valid db2 user account?

I have existing user id in this machine, which i used to install the db2 database. Can I make this user as a db2 system user? If so what are the steps.

Comment: and what did you try so far ?

Comment: i didnt create os user. I am thinking of to use my exisiting windows os user - which is present there before installing db2, is it possible to change this user to a db2 system user

Answer (score 1):

There are no users in DB2 that are not OS users. The client software  makes this a bit confusing: what they show as "users" are actually grants given to the (externally defined) users.

you can grant privileges to arbitrary users or groups, and no verification is done if those users and groups exist at that time.

However, to connect to the database and exercise the granted privileges you must authenticate first, and for that you must have the user defined in the OS (or another configured authentication service, such as an LDAP directory).

Answer (score 1):

All versions of Db2-server rely on the underlying operating system, or LDAP to authenticate users. Db2-server has no concept of 'internal' users.

You can use your own account, or any Windows-account to administer Db2-Server on Windows. That might be what you mean by a "system user account", but Db2 does not use that terminology of "system user". Instead Db2-server on Windows understands a user with DBADM rights, or SECADM rights, or a user who is a member of SYSADM_GROUP. These are well explained in the documentation.

If you accepted the defaults when installing Db2-server on Windows, then there will be two local groups created by the installation, called DB2USERS and DB2ADMNS. (You don't have to use these local groups, any groups will suffice, as long as you tell Db2 about them).

You can add your own account (or any other Windows accounts) to the local group DB2ADMNS (or to the group that is the SYSADM_GROUP), using Windows GUIs or command-line commands. The users can also be domain-users.

You should then configure the Db2-server instance configuration item SYSADM_GROUP with the value DB2ADMNS. You can do this via the command line (db2cwadmin.bat > db2 update dbm cfg using SYSADM_GROUP db2admns  ). This then allows Db2-server to know that anyone who is a member of that group can have SYSADM rights on the Db2-server instance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I know , I didn't create the local groups DB2ADMNS and DB2USERS while installing the db2. Is it still possible to make my existing os user, to db2 user account. I have system admin privileges for this user. Aalso which db2 command can be used to verify the existing db2 users, anything like that to verify the user accounts in db2.

Comment: Don't ask new questions in a comment-thread, create a new question instead. The local-groups DB2ADMNS and DB2USERS are a big convenience when you understand them.    Your personal Windows account can get access to Db2 database if db2admin (or a suitably privileged account) GRANTS relevant rights on the database. But you also need to administer the *instance* of Db2 as distinct from the *databases*, and that is the value of the SYSADM_GROUP concept.  **READ THE DOCUMENTATION***